# Converse of first isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Prove or disprove the following statement :

> If the mapping from $G/\ker\phi$ to $\phi(G)$, given by $g\ker\phi\mapsto\phi(g)$, is an isomorphism, then $\phi:G\to\bar G$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by the converse ?

Comment: Can you be more precise by what you mean by "the converse" ? It's true that any isomorphism is a quotient.

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest thing to a converse I can think of.

> Let $G, G'$ be groups, let $\phi: G \rightarrow G'$ be a function, and let $K = \{ g \in G : \phi(g) = e_{G'}\}$.  Suppose that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $\phi(G)$ is a subgroup of $G'$, and suppose that the function $\overline{\phi}:G/K \rightarrow \phi(G)$ given by $\overline{\phi}(xK) = \phi(x)$ is well defined and an isomorphism.  Then $\phi$ is a group homomorphism.

Answer: Yes, because $\phi(xy) = \overline{\phi}(xyK) = \overline{\phi}(xK) \overline{\phi}(yK) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$.

Comment: So you think that the converse is true?

Comment: You haven't clearly stated the converse.  I just stated a naive guess as to what you meant and proved it.

Comment: If you want a definite answer, please edit your question and make it more clear.  It would be very helpful for you to give a precise statement of what you want to be proved/disproved.